# How to set black color bottom of the image and in that set text?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ayxw.jpg)

How to set black color bottom of the image and in that set text ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
https://codepen.io/bartassmo/pen/wvyJORZ
```

or make it with img inside div, and position:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
}
.item__content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```